# Height of a .slice() subset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a height of a subset which I get with a `.slice()` function:

```
$('#chatroom-table tr').slice(0, 10);
```

However, when I call this:

```
$('#chatroom-table tr').slice(0, 10).height();
```

I get the height of the first row in said subset. Is it possible to get the sum of height of all 10 table rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get sum of tr heights

```
var height=0;
$.each($('#chatroom-table tr').slice(0, 10),
       function(r,row){
                height+=$(row).height();
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum of all values that you had

I'm watched this video for simple explained to use [reduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVCYa_bnITg)